# Random logout in .Net 1.1 Website

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, logout, asp.net-1.1

In a .Net 1.1 web site I manage, I am getting people saying they are logged out randomly.

I did not find any pattern.

I have a uptime robot set, to alert me when the app pool is re-started. So that is not the case.

It mostly happens at heavy load time.

Till now, I have just found one problem,

A lot of places code like this is written,

Response.Redirect("aa.aspx");

As this can cause session to be expired, this could be an issue.

but then why is it not happening everytime, and why is it random..

Please give some idea on this..

Comment: can it be a case, that session has been removed because of timeout? I mean, if clients leave for 15 min(default session timeout), than the session will be removed

Comment: No..All that are complaining are like...they were using and suddenly its logged out..

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I couldn't find the docs for .Net 1.1 but this may help

You could try the Forms Authentication Timeout value in the web.config.

Setting it's value to a larger number of seconds may help

[This blog post covers it in more details](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/08/430011.aspx)

Comment: I use Session for authentication, and which is set to - 120 already